# TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement got PathElement

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, datastore

I am trying to push the data to GCP DataStore, The below code snippet works fine in Jupyter Notebook but it is throwing error in VS Code.

```html
def load_data_json(self, kind_name, data_with_qp_ID, qp_id):

        #Load the data in JSON format to upload into the DataStore
        data_with_qp_ID_as_JSON = self.convert_DF_to_JSON(data_with_qp_ID, qp_id)
        #Loop to iterate through the JSON format and upload into the GCS Storage
        for data in data_with_qp_ID_as_JSON.keys():
            with self.client.transaction():
                incomplete_key = self.client.key(kind_name)
                task = datastore.Entity(key=incomplete_key)
                task.update(data_with_qp_ID_as_JSON[data])
                self.client.put(task)
                
        return 'Ingestion Successful - Data Store Repository'
```

I have defined the name of the bucket in "Kind Name", data_with_qp_id is a pandas dataframe, qp_id is the name of the column name in pandas. Please see the error message that I get below,

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ajaykrishnan/Desktop/Projects/Sprint 3/Data Migration/DataMigration_v1.1/main2.py", line 139, in <module>
    write_datastore_db.load_data_json(ds_kindname, bookmarks_data_with_qp_ID, qp_id)
  File "/Users/ajaykrishnan/Desktop/Projects/Sprint 3/Data Migration/DataMigration_v1.1/pkg/repository/ds_repository.py", line 50, in load_data_json
    self.client.put(task)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/client.py", line 597, in put
    self.put_multi(entities=[entity], retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/client.py", line 634, in put_multi
    current.put(entity)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/transaction.py", line 315, in put
    super(Transaction, self).put(entity)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py", line 227, in put
    _assign_entity_to_pb(entity_pb, entity)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py", line 373, in _assign_entity_to_pb
    bare_entity_pb = helpers.entity_to_protobuf(entity)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/helpers.py", line 208, in entity_to_protobuf
    key_pb = entity.key.to_protobuf()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/key.py", line 298, in to_protobuf
    key.path.append(element)
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement got PathElement.
```

My environment is as follows,

Mac OS Monterey V12.06
Python - Conda 3.9.12

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear this error. It was an issue with Protobuf library that my environment was using. I downgraded the version of protobuf from 4.x.x to 3.20.1 and it worked.